# React toastify is not working , when page is redirect to another page. But it is working on same page

Tags: reactjs, react-notifications

I use react-toastify for toast notification, but it is not working when my page is redirec to another page.

> It is not working mydata is save to the data base.
> It is working when my page is not redirect.

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

const loginUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await fetch("/signin", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),

    });

    const data = await res.json();
    if (res.status === 422 || !res) {
        warningAlert();
        console.log(res);
        console.log("Invalid Credentials")
    } else {
        successAlert();
        dispatch({ type: "USER", payload: true });
        // console.log(res);
        history.push("/");

    }
}
```

> the above code is for login. here notification is not working in `else` condition, but working in `if` condition.

> Above Mentioned alert

```
    const successAlert = () => {
    // window.alert("Invalid Credentials");
    toast("User logged in successfully", {
        position: "top-right",
        autoClose: 2000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,

    });
}


    const warningAlert = () => {
    // window.alert("Invalid Credentials");
    toast.error("Invalid Credentials", {
        position: "top-right",
        autoClose: 2000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,

    });
}
```

Comment: Which version of react-toastify are you using? Also are there any errors in the console?

Comment: am using 8.0.3 , and there is no error in the console

Comment: Does removing the redirection help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to use `<ToastContainer/>` in root of you project so that this container is accessible from all the pages. and then call the fucntion

[Official Doc](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify)

Comment: THANKS, BRO ... I FORGET TO ADD THE CONTAINER IN MY APP.JS

Answer (score 5):

In my case, It was `window.location.href = '/user'` which i was using for going to homepage after user is created.
This will cause whole application to reload(reset) and thus Notification will not work regardless of where you keep your `<ToastContainer/>` component.

Make sure, you are using react-router methods(history.push or navigate) for route change.